# Angular JS: Inject service within app.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-services, route-provider

I want the users not to go to certain pages at least they've logged in before. I'm currently using this:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $route, $location)
{
    var restrictedPages = 
            [   
                '/Survey/', '/Survey/Detalle', '/Survey/Accepted', '/Account/Profile',
                '/Auction/Detail', '/Survey/Accepted'
            ];

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (ev, next, current)
    {
        var nextPath = $location.path();
        var nextRoute = $route.routes[nextPath];

        if(restrictedPages.indexOf(nextPath) !== -1)
        {
            $location.path('/home');
        }
    });
});
```

My problem here is that I want to inject inside of this piece of code my AccountService. How can I achieve this? Because the loading-order is the following

- app.js  (the code presented is inside here)
- homeService.js
- accountService.js

I truly believe this is not the right way to go but it seems so simple and the only thing I'm missing is the account service injection.

Comment: How is the `AccountService` defined?

Comment: What do you mean by "injection"? A service can be injected into another service. But a "piece of code" can't be injected.

Comment: Are you saying you want this run block to instantiate and reference your AccountService?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry, by piece of code I meant a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this module, which includes a accountService that uses implicit DI:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('accountService', function($rootScope) {
  // $rootScope is implicitly injected
})
.run(['$rootScope', '$route', '$location', 'accountService', function ($rootScope, $route, $location, accountService)
{
    var restrictedPages = 
            [   
                '/Survey/', '/Survey/Detalle', '/Survey/Accepted', '/Account/Profile',
                '/Auction/Detail', '/Survey/Accepted'
            ];

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (ev, next, current)
    {
        var nextPath = $location.path();
        var nextRoute = $route.routes[nextPath];

        if(restrictedPages.indexOf(nextPath) !== -1 && !accountService.isLoggedIn())
        {
            $location.path('/home');
        }
    });
}]);
```

if you want more documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: I did not know you could inject a service within this.  But how this get to work when the account service hasn't been loaded yet? I mean the actual javascript file

Comment: you can use https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization for start application when angular is ready